# new Placemark, не работает опция preset для маркера

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Не могу заставить работать опцию `preset`. Вот пример кода:

```
var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark(
    [ coords_arr[1], coords_arr[0] ],
    {
        iconContent: icon_text,
        balloonContent: balloon_content
    }, {
        // Иконка метки будет растягиваться под размер ее содержимого.
        preset: 'twirl#redStretchyIcon', //icon_preset,
        balloonContentSize: [458, 320], // размер нашего кастомного балуна в пикселях
        balloonLayout: "default#imageWithContent", // указываем что содержимое балуна кастомная херь
        balloonImageHref: css_location+'/img/map/balloon.png', // Картинка заднего фона балуна
        balloonImageOffset: [-229, -380], // смещание балуна, надо подогнать под стрелочку
        balloonImageSize: [458, 380], // размер картинки-бэкграунда балуна
        balloonShadow: false
    }
);
```

В результате имею  самую дефолтную голубую "точку" без "растягивания". Подскажите, что делать?

P.S.: в API 2.0 все работает как надо (только там я использую `new ymaps.GeoObject()`). В API 2.1 не работает ни через `Placemark()`, ни через `GeoObject()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В версии 2.1 шаблоны `twirl#...` заменены на `islands#...`. Причем аналогов некоторым шаблонам в новой версии нету (например канули в лету многие иконки).

Полный список того, что сейчас поддерживается можно посмотреть [здесь](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/option.presetStorage-docpage/)

**Обновлено:**

Появились иконки в несколько ином виде. Полный список по ссылке выше.

Comment: Спасибо! Видел же этот док, но совершенно не бросилось в глаза что там другой "префикс" у шаблонов.